# Flutter: How to Rotate `ClipOval` with `Transform.rotate()` without rotating the image inside?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have attempted to rotate a `ClipOval` using `Transform.rotate()`, but the entire image is rotated.

My goal is to have the image displayed centered without the 45 degree rotation.

**My Code:**

```
Transform.rotate(
    angle: 1,
    child: ClipOval(
        child: Container(
            child: Image.network(
                "https://img.freepik.com/premium-vector/person-avatar-design_24877-38137.jpgw=2000",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 200,
                height: 300,
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

````
import 'dart:math' as math;

Transform.rotate(
  angle: 180 * math.pi / 180,
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.details,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    onPressed: null,
  ),
)```
````

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**